# Why doesn't this always create a triangle?

Tags: netlogo

I would expect this code to create a triangle each time, but instead many
times it goes through the wrap-around, creating a zigzag line or 
disconnected angle pieces.  Why is that? Is it a bug?

Create a go button (not a forever button) to run this code

```
to go 
  clear-all 
  create-turtles 3 
  ask turtles 
    [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      create-links-to (other turtles)] 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links take the shortest path, which may go around the world edges, which (in the default world topology) are connected to each other.

Go into the "Settings..." dialog and turn off wrapping if it isn't the behavior you wanted.

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology for details.